# Evaluating determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $\{\alpha_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be distinct numbers. What is the determinant of the $n$ by $n$ matrix
\begin{gather}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{1}^{n-1} & \alpha_{1}^{n-2} & \cdots & 1 \\
  \alpha_{2}^{n-1} & \alpha_{2}^{n-2} & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  \alpha_{n}^{n-1} & \alpha_{n}^{n-2} & \cdots & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
?

Comment: Do you mean [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)?

Comment: Oh, i didn't know :) thanks @GAVD

Comment: However, the columns aren't in the same order, so i guess there might i some cases be a minus sing?

Comment: What is the easiest, or rather most elemntary way of proving the the product formula?

Comment: @BasicUser if $P$ is a permutation matrix that switch two columns, [then](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221668/determinant-of-permutation-matrix) $\det(P)=-1$. Now if you have $n$ columns, you need $\nu=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ switch $P_1,\ldots,P_\nu$ to transform your matrix in a Vandermonde matrix. The you can use $\det(V)=\det(AP_1\ldots P_{\nu})=\det(A)(-1)^{\nu}$.